# Expand height of parent div with the content of inner child div

Tags: css, html, height, expand

I dont have much detail for this but hope I could draw on others knowledge on this matter.

I have a div which has a minimum height set on it. This div contains content and is repeated multiple times in a .net repeater.

This works fine.

Within the main div is another div. This contains more content of which can span multiple lines. The issue I have is that if the child div is higher than the parent div, the parent div does not expand in height. And as its within a repeater, the content of the child div expands onto the next parent div. Is there a way via css I can expand the parent div so that expands with the content of the child div.

This is a very much scaled down version of my markup:

```
    <div class="row">This is content ... blah blah<div class="child">ahdshfjhdsfjk <br/><br /><br /><br /><br />jkljlkj<br />jjkljl<br /></div></div>
```

Any help would be great as to how to fix this

Comment: This works as expected. What are the styles?

Answer (score 3):

From what I remember you can try adding a "clear" at the end of your containing div like so:

```
<div class="row">
   This is content ... blah blah
   <div class="child">
      ahdshfjhdsfjk
      <br/><br /><br /><br /><br />
      jkljlkj
      <br />
      jjkljl
      <br />
   </div>
   <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

Comment: or better, <div style="clear: both"></div> as that doesn't add an extra blank line

Comment: Thanks but no luck with this!

Comment: @ Niall , at the runtime with jquery you can find the height of child div and accordingly adjust the parent div right $('$divid').height() and change the parent div.

Comment: @Niall, You could try moving the <br style="clear: both" /> to inside the child div to see if that makes a difference. Ultimately it could be a number of things and will no doubt require some CSS debugging. If you have not already you should look into installing Firefox (http://getfirefox.com) with the Firebug (http://getfirebug.com) extension. Firebug will allow you to inspect elements and edit CSS on the fly. It's an invaluable tool when it comes to finding CSS errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's better to know standard html and css and not proprietary .NET stuff that hides things from you. What you show should do what you want. The issue lies in the CSS and without that, everything's a wild guess but probably related to the inside div being floated or otherwise positioned.